# How to show decimal values in highcharts graph?

Tags: highcharts, tooltip, data-visualization

```
series: [{
        name: 'name',
        type: 'spline',
        data: d1,
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.y:.2f}%</b>'
        }
}]
d1=[0.12,-1.58,-0.8]
```

Show in graph 0.00,1.00,0.00

Comment: Defaulty it shows the decimals: http://jsfiddle.net/muv7j0w3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Highcharts.numberFormat` function in combination with the `formatter` function, as **Ahmed Sayed** noted (see http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Highcharts.numberFormat).

For your specific code, you would format it this way:

```
series: [{
    name: 'name',
    type: 'spline',
    data: d1,
    tooltip: {
      // format the tooltip to return the y-axis value to two decimal places
      formatter: function() { 
        return this.series.name + ': <b>' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y,2) + '%</b>';
      }
    }
}]
```

I hope this is helpful for you.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `formatter` option instead where you provide a javascript function to return the value in the format you need

```
tooltip: {
  formatter: function() { 
    return getTooltip(this.y);
  }
}
```